# Stopping terminal tab update on ssh

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal, iterm2

I understand that this is a possible duplicate question. However, I could not find any satisfying answer and so I am asking this question yet again.

When I SSH into a remote machine, I do not want Terminal/iTerm to automatically update tab and window title.
I have tried different suggested solutions like setting $PROMPT_COMMAND to be null and explored various settings in iterm2.

None of that however, has worked for me.
Please let me know if you have a solution for this.

I am using OSX Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

In iterm2, you can control this with Preferences -> Profiles -> Terminal, uncheck "Terminal may set tab/window title".